# jquery ajax post with json content type returning bad request as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below example code which works in my local development environment but when publishing to a live environment which uses HTTPS and uses the .NET bundling for the javascript, and ELMAH for error logging, this no longer works as intended.

Instead of a JSON content response I get a HTML content response with the `responseText` "Bad Request" and no `responseJSON` property so this code results in a javascript error.

Does anyone know why the content type would get changed? presumably due to this being in a live environment and a response code of 400? but I'm not sure what is going on here.

Controller:

```
        public JsonResult JsonModelErrorResult()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors);
            return Json(errors);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
...
            if (results != null && results.Any())
            {
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SearchResults", "No results found");
                return this.JsonModelErrorResult();
            }
        }
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax("/Controller/GetData/", {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json"
            })
            .done((result) => {
            })
            .fail((xhr) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.errors(xhr.responseJSON);
                }, 200);
            })
            .always(() => {
            });
```

---

**Update:**

This is the response header when I view the response for the request in Chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:08:23 GMT
Content-Length: 11
```

and the returned value from the ajax call is a Jquery jqXHR object with a `responseText` property of `"Bad Request"` and a content type of `"text/html"`

**UPDATE 2:** 
This is the custom errors setup in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/NotAuthorised" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/NotAuthorised" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

When testing I changed the mode to "Off" but this did not work in the live environment which is IIS8, maybe I missed something that need to be updated in order for IIS to do this correctly or that the `defaultRedirect="~/Error">` should have also been removed? 
but adding the line
`Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`
into the JsonModelErrorResult code has stopped this content/html error with the line "Bad Request" being returned.

Comment: Not sure, having in mind the environment, but have you tried this  Response.Headers.Add('Content-type', 'text/json');
Response.Headers.Add('Content-type', 'application/json');

Comment: It could be that you're running into an issue at the ASP.NET or IIS level and that your code (at least server side) is okay (which might explain the content type change).  An HTTP 400 could be returned for a variety of reasons such as a request header being too long, special characters in the query string or the size of the HTTP request is too large.  I would inspect the HTTP request that you're making and also check the Event Viewer on the server to see if the framework is logging an error for you.  Let me know what you find, I'm curious about this one.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Yea I think it might be IIS related but it's difficult to replicate. I don't have the same version of IIS locally and the server has URL rewriting setup for redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. I thought it might have been custom errors but I disabled them to test it and this still happens. My request header content length is usually small, the problem always occurs where I get a `text/html` `Content-Type` response header and here is one example of the request payload `{"SegmentId":230,"CountryIds":[],"ContainerIds":[],"ClosureIds":[]}`.

Comment: the live environment is windows server 2012 with IIS8, and I only have Windows 7 and IIS7 locally.. and our dev environment does not match this either at the moment so I can't test it there either.. I am going to try explicitly setting the JSON() content type and if that fails also trying to change the `Response` in my MVC controller action.. to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Pricey I think forcing the content type is going down the wrong path.  Did you check the Event Viewer?  What is the *actual* HTML content that you get back in your Ajax call?  Can you post the exact response?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Yes I agree, that was a work around not a solution. setting the content type for the jsonResult and also on the Response object in MVC did not fix this anyway. I have updated my post with details about the response, I still think this must be IIS8 or a custom error instead

Comment: @Pricey Try looking here: `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`.  Do you see anything in the log file corresponding to a 400 code?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Doesn't seem to be anything in there for the particular website, there are some logs for another website on that server, I'm presuming it needs to be enabled? The IIS Logs for the website do show the 400's but its just a time and date and shows the HTTP 400 and the URL for the POST but no further info

Comment: @Pricey Right after you set the `Response.StatusCode` add this line of code:  `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true`.  This tells IIS not to intercept the request and use its own error page.  Let me know the result.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Hi, that setting fixed the issue, I don't really understand why though. I have not specifically told IIS to treat a 400 error with a custom error result, so not sure why it does this.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson If you want to add an answer then I can mark it as such, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Pricey I added the answer.  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right after you set the `Response.StatusCode` add this line of code:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

This tells IIS not to intercept the request and use its own error page.